# time is not defined Python

Tags: python, time

I am trying to understand python time (mainly so I can get the program to wait). When I run these 3 lines:

```
while True:
    time.sleep(1)
    print("BREAK")
```

I get the error:

> NameError: name 'time' is not defined

What is the problem?

Comment: Have you used `import time`?

Comment: No. Is that the issue?

Comment: Sure,you should learn about python module.

Comment: try this ```from time import time```.

Comment: As a beginner in Python you should start with the [Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/)

Comment: @Cs150 that's not going to help the OP... just `import time` is fine here... `from time import time` will just cause an `AttributeError` for what the OP is trying to do...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

simply type `import time` before your code, this will fix the problem.